# Espresso: Verify the listview items in Alert dialog

Tags: kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-espresso

the screenshot of the view is here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9zv9.png

I tried using

```
val ANCHOR_SIZE_OPTION_1 = ViewElement(withContentDescription("3/16\""), "anchor size option 1")
```

in its Robot but test run throws back error that "3/16" is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the mistake:

the ViewMatcher i should have been using is withText, and not withContentDescription